# Crazy Iterated Square Roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, radicals, function-and-relation-composition, nested-radicals, geometric-series

I was messing around with infinite square root nesting problems like
$$w_1=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{...}}}$$
which is an easy example. I decided to try one where the terms inside of the square roots form a geometric sequence:
$$w_2=\sqrt{2^{-1}+\sqrt{2^{-2}+\sqrt{2^{-3}+\sqrt{...}}}}$$
but I can't figure it out. I figured that I probably have to set it equal to $x$ and define $x$ as a function of itself, but I'm not sure how to do that. A similar problem that I did figure out how to do was
$$w_3=\sqrt{2^{-1}+\sqrt{2^{-2}+\sqrt{2^{-4}+\sqrt{2^{-8}+\sqrt{...}}}}}$$
because if you multiply it by $\sqrt{2}$, it collapses to a problem of the first form that I mentioned. Any ideas about that second problem?

Comment: The value appears to be approximately $1.285736763357$, for what it's worth.

Comment: In *Mathematica*, the function `R[n_] := Fold[Sqrt[#1 + #2] &, 0, 2^-Reverse[Range[n]]]` followed by `N[R[1000],50]` gives the result to 50 decimal places of precision.  A search of this number via the inverse symbolic calculator yields no results.

Comment: Interestingly, when I expand the iterated fraction to the left, meaning I let the iteration begin not at $2^{-1}$ but at $2^0$ or $2^1$ or even $2^{64}$ (or $2^{2k}$)  I arrive at a value near $2^{k}+0.35355$ whose right summand -by W|A- is near  ${1 \over 2 \sqrt 2}$ ... so that we might write $ \lim_{k \to \infty} \sqrt {2^{2k}+\cdots + \sqrt {2^1 + \sqrt{2^0 + \sqrt{2^{-1} + \sqrt{2^{-2} + \cdots }}}}} \to 2^k + \sqrt{ \frac 18 } $

Comment: problem 2 can be reformulated . Let $b=\sqrt2$ then we can write: 
$$w_2 \cdot b = \sqrt{1+b^0\sqrt{1+b^1 \sqrt{1+b^2 \sqrt{1+b^3 \sqrt{...}}}}} $$ However I'm not nearer with this...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Yeah, we can actually prove that equality. If we let 
$$r_1=\lim_{k\to\infty}\Big(\sqrt{2^{2k}+\sqrt{...}}-2^k\Big)$$
$$r_2=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2^{2k}+\sqrt{...}}+2^k}{2^k}$$
it is easy to prove (using the difference of squares identity) that $r_1\cdot r_2=1/\sqrt{2}$. Since the limit $r_2=2$ is almost trivial, we have $r_1=1/2\sqrt{2}$ as you calculated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $$G_k(x) = (2x)^{k+1} + \sqrt{G_{k+1}(x)},$$ then $G_0(x)$ is the generating function of sequence [A274850](http://oeis.org/A274850) and $$\sqrt{G_0(1/4)} = \sqrt{2^{-1}+\sqrt{2^{-2}+\sqrt{2^{-3}+\sqrt{...}}}}$$ but it is unlikely that this has a closed form value. More generally, let
$$ f(x,q) = x + \sqrt{f(xq,q)}.$$
We can expand it in a power series
$$ f(x,q) = 1 + x\frac{2}{2-q} - x^2\frac{q^2}{(2-q)^2(2-q^2)} + x^3\frac{2q^3}{(2-q)^3(2-q^2)(2-q^3)} + \dots$$
and now $G_0(x) = f(2x,2x).$

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't answered my exact question, but I have managed to compute the values of some similar "crazy iterated square roots" in which the coefficients inside are in geometric progression. For example,
$$\sqrt{a^2+\sqrt{4a^2+\sqrt{16a^2+\sqrt{64a^2+...}}}}=a+1$$
and
$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{a^2+a\sqrt{a^4+a^2\sqrt{a^6+a^3\sqrt{a^8+...}}}}}=\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4}}{2}$$
Additionally, we have the following involving the Fibonacci numbers, with $F_0=F_1=1$ (not exactly geometric progression, but whatever):
$$\sqrt{1+F_1{-1+F_2\sqrt{1+F_3\sqrt{-1+...}}}}=2$$